# Vim pasting 4 spaces, pressing '=', indents to ^I rather than spaces

Tags: vim

I am a python developer and I work for a company where the python convention for indentation is two spaces rather than four.

So I notice this problem when I paste code from vim:

This is the text I am trying to paste:

```
def four_spaces():
    print "hello"
```

This text is copied in mac from Chrome using `<cmd> c`. Note that I am using `vim` in iTerm in the Mac OS X.

Below are the steps for me to pasting this in vim using  as I am using a mac:

1. `:set paste` *Turn Paste mode on*
2. `a` *Append mode*
3. `<Cmd> v` *Pasting in Mac*
4. Result shown in **Snippet 4**. *Note that it's 4 spaces*
5. `v kk` *Visual mode to select the above
6. `=` *Fix indentation*
7. Result shown in **Snippet 7**. *Note the ^I*

**Snippet 4 (listmode on)**

```
def four_spaces():$
    print "hello"$
```

**Snippet 7 (listmode on)**

```
def four_spaces():$
^Iprint "hello"$
```

This is what my .vimrc file looks like for those interested:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/20b2a1f43125c0d39932bf430c8137dc

**Problem:**

The problem I am facing with right now is that I have a tab character rather than 2 space when I use `=`. This is problematic because python relies on tab indentation and it cannot allow tab characters and spaces to co-exist together. I am trying to figure out how come = doesn't use expandtab.

Question: 
How can I paste using `<Cmd> v` and such that:

1. Vim formats my code properly to 2 spaces
2. *OR* when I use `=` to fix indentation it won't replace it with `^I`?

Comment: Is the shiftwidth also set to 2 spaces? `:set ts? sw? et?`

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523953/vim-pasting-4-spaces-pressing-indents-to-i-rather-than-spaces; please don't post to several SE sites in parallel!